# In R, retrieve the code / contents for a plot assigned to a variable

Tags: r, variables, plot

Let's say I've assigned a plot in R to a variable name.  Here's an example I'm currently working on, although any `variable <- plotting code` example will do:

```
myplot <- wireframe(sag.pr.dev ~ Col*Row, data=t22mapee, 
           xlab = "col",
           ylab = "row",
           ylim = c(33,1),
           main = "T22 PR Sag Deviation",
           #zlim=c(-0.6, 0.2),
           drape = TRUE,
           colorkey = TRUE,
           scales = list(arrows=FALSE,cex=.5, tick.number = 10, z = list(arrows=F), distance =c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)),
           col.regions = terrain.colors(100),
           screen = list(z =  30, x = -60))
```

Typing `myplot` will draw the plot on demand.  But my question is: Is there a command/method to retrieve the code stored under `myplot` later?  I'm aware of things like `ls(myplot)` and the like, but that only gives a list of commands invoked and not the actual code.

I need to do this because I have some plot code that has rolled off my screen in the current R session (due to foolishly listing out a few very long data frames), and I don't exactly remember how I created a few particular plots.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `history()` or just up arrow the cursor.

Comment: Scrolling doesn't work in this case because at some point, I  exceeded the max number of lines in the command window during the session.  history(max.show = Inf) also doesn't show my command history all the way back to the beginning of the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES!  You should be able to get back the code using

```
myplot$call
```

You can see this by typing `str(myplot)` and browsing the output.